# Facebook permission approved but still not working

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I've developed a Facebook app which reads likes from users.

Facebook has just approved the user_likes permission, and I can see it live in Status & Review section.

However, when trying to use the app, I still see the message:

"Some of the permissions below have not been approved for use by Facebook."

and no likes can be read.

All the submissions has been approved and the app status is online.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Are you sure your app is not asking for any additional permissions? Does a user without a role in the app gets asked for `user_likes` in the login dialog? Are you able to successfully test the functionality with a user account that does have a role in the app?

Comment: Yes no other requests are there in Status & Review tab. Yes with a Test User I get likes correctly and no, users are not asked to share their likes in the login dialog.

Comment: OK, sometimes there’s a little glitch, where the permission is shown a approved, but still doesn’t work. File a bug report and ask them to look into it for you, https://developers.facebook.com/bugs